# Cache Busting: Parameters vs Folders vs Files

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cross-browser, browser-cache

I am looking into best practice / browser-proof techniques of ensuring that the browser cache is refreshed when I push a new update to my site, containing changes to html/css/js etc.

So far I have implemented a parameter based system next to all files that are loaded but I don't believe it is working consistently across browsers.

I was thinking of implementing folder based versioning, is this a good / bad / useless option? Example:

```
|--Site
   |--redirect.v1
      |--redirect.html
      |--redirect.html 
   |--login.v1
      |--login.html
      |--login.css
   |--home.v1
      |--index.html
      |--index.css
   |--shared.v1
      |--js
         |--bootstrap.min.js
         |--tether.min.js
         |--jquery-3.2.1.min.js
         |--ie-detector.min.js
      |--images
         |--logo.jpg
         |--loading.gif
         |--favicons
            |--favicon.ico
            |--favicon-16x16.png
            |--mstile-144x144
```

Example file loading within the HTML:

```
<script src="../shared.v1/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../shared.v1/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="../shared.v1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../etc.v1/etc/etc.min.js"></script>
```

If any update occurs to a file in a folder I would like to simply update the physical folder name and deceleration in the HTML.

Comment: _“If any update occurs to a file in a folder I would like to simply update the physical folder name”_ - well that would mean that for a change that occurred in _one single file_, you would invalidate the cache for _all of the files_ in that folder at the same time ...

Comment: @CBroe understood, but I am willing to do this if it's much more potent at forcing a cache clear?

Comment: It is not. By changing a URL to a new one, your are forcing the client to download it again. At what “level” in the URL you do this - folder name or file name - does not make any difference in that regard. Your approach just has this additional, potentially massive downside, but it does not improve anything.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, so would you recommend then main effort in cache busting to be in parameterizing of the physical file names?